# What could be reason behind "wget: unable to resolve host address ‘archive.ubuntu.com’" error

Tags: 18.04, wget

I'm trying to download the **netboot ubuntu 18.04 image** and using [this link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/)

It has directories and file directly. So trying to download all the files and sub-directory recursively...
For that, I'm using following command:

```
wget -m http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/
```

which gives following error:

```
--2020-03-16 14:23:12--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer- 
amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘archive.ubuntu.com’
```

Not sure what is the reason behind this error, any help/direction is appreciated!

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is this: [Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with arbitrary files in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it)

Comment: I have gone through all the wget but, they are not getting the above error

Comment: I'm now confused, what exactly are you looking for? You want reason behind the error **OR** ```ubuntu-installer``` to be downloaded using ```wget```??

Comment: Try ```wget -r -np -R "index.html*" http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer```, that should do the trick!

Comment: what is the reason for the error?

Comment: First of all, make it clear in your question what are you looking for, don't put ambiguous questions here... This could be a case [wget: unable to resolve host address `http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821521/wget-unable-to-resolve-host-address-http).